# Send path of SDWebImage stored image to a UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, sdwebimage

I need to be able to get a path to images that cached.

While I am wondering if there is a way to do this using SDWebImage, I could probably get away with just having the knowledge to return a path to an image stored in the cache so I can display it within a uiwebview inside an image tag.

Comment: :- Can you please post the solution ,how you have done with SDwebimage in webview

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to this https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/25 it would seem you can simply refer to the image by it's original url and it will be correctly picked up from cache.

Comment: Now, that's cool! I would have never suspected it to be that easy.

Comment: no.. it doesn't work, and the post you linked doesn't say that it does

Comment: "This way, UIWebView and all other components using NSURLConnection will automatically benefits from SDURLCache's store."