# How can I used the cache image of SDWebimage in UIWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiwebview, sdwebimage

How can I take the advantage of `SDWebCache` in `UIWebview`.
I am loading the `UIWebview` using `loadhtmlWithString` with Image tag in the html & passing url in it but it is downloading  the image again instead of taking it from cache.
Can any body tell what i am doing wrong

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use SDWebImage for UIWebview Caching. But you can use several caching methods to cahe your web page.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348696/how-to-cache-content-in-uiwebview-for-faster-loading-later-on), [this](http://robnapier.net/offline-uiwebview-nsurlprotocol) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826820/uiwebview-webpage-caching-for-offline-viewing)

Comment: Then what does this means http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959251/send-path-of-sdwebimage-stored-image-to-a-uiwebview?rq=1